# Extracting rasters from multiple NetCDF files based on date values in Python

Tags: python, raster, netcdf

I have multiple NetCDF files (one for each year) that contain daily rainfall values for Australia.

At present I am able to extract the specific days I want by reading from a .csv file that contains the list of dates I want. From this it then outputs each day as a raster file.

However, the script I have at the moment only allows me to do this one year at a time. I'm fairly new to python, and rather than re-running the script many times by changing the NetCDF file it reads in (as well as the list of dates in the .csv file) I was hoping to get some assistance in creating a loop that will read through the list of NetCDF's.

I understand that modules such as NetCDF4 are available to treat all files as one, but despite many hours reading what others have done, I am none the wiser.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import os, sys
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script arguments
netCDF = "G:\\Gridded_rain\\DAILY\\netcdf\\Daily_analysis_V3"
rainfall = "G:\\output_test\\r_"

arcpy.env.workspace = netCDF

# Read Date from csv file
eveDate = open ("G:\\selectdate_TEST1.csv", "r")
headerLine = eveDate.readline()
valueList = headerLine.split(",")
dateValueIndex = valueList.index("Date")
eventList = []
for line in eveDate.readlines():
    segmenLine = line.split(",")
    variable = "pre"
    x_dimension = "lon"
    y_dimension = "lat"
    band_dimension = ""
    #dimensionValues = "r_time 1900025"

    valueSelectionMethod = "BY_VALUE"
    outFile = "Pre"
    # extract dimensionValues from csv file
    arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md("pre.2011.nc", variable, x_dimension, y_dimension, outFile, band_dimension, segmenLine[dateValueIndex], valueSelectionMethod)
    print "layer done"
    #copy and save as raster tif file
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(outFile, rainfall + segmenLine[dateValueIndex] + ".tif" , "", "", "", "NONE", "NONE", "")
    print "raster done"
```

The NetCDF files are named from pre.1900.nc through to pre.2011.nc

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is format for `dateValueIndex`? And post some values.

Comment: So you would as I guess from the current question prose, either want to handle an argument and use this as variable instead of the hardcoded literal `pre.2011.nc` to access the matching netcdf file or embed another loop level (outer) that goes somehow like `for year in range(1900, 2012):` and then digests the files. Open question: Do the parameter files also have to be matched? SHall I give a sample based on that?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is really about python command line arguments you could add something like:

```
import sys
year = int(sys.argv[1])
nc_name = 'pre.%d.nc' % (year,)
```

and then use this `nc_name`as filepathargument in your `arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md`call

The other possibility would be to as suggested in comment to question hard code another layer like so:

```
for year in range(1900, 2012):
    nc_name = 'pre.%d.nc' % (year,)
```

and then call `arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md` etc.

Comment: Thanks Dilettant... I tried your first suggestion however it came up with an error saying "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'args'"                                                I then tried your second suggestion of putting "for year in range...etc". And though it appeared to work, when I checked the files they were only the correct rasters for one year. I did this on a sample of NetCDF's from 1979 to 1981 and only the rasters from 1980 were correct.

Comment: Polyglot leads to babylon - sorry it is sys.argv which is a list when you call your prpgram with say argument 2011, then this list will have two entries: the name of your program in position 0 and 2011 as string in position 1. so sys.argv[1] would be '2011'

Comment: I did this on a sample of NetCDF's from 1979 to 1981, with two dates for each year in the .csv file and only the rasters from 1980 were correct. 
Since I needed to do my subsequent analysis ASAP, I found a workaround by extracting all days for all years separately into a single folder and copying the necessary rasters/days from one folder over to another folder based on their name using "arcpy.CopyRaster_management"
If it is helpful to anyone else, I’ll continue to try any suggestions provided. If not,  I have found a way around having to read all NetCDF’s to begin with.